# Android gradle build duplicate files during packaging httpmime

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error when I try to build my android project. First I got an error that I could not run things because of problems in AndroidMultiPartEntity.java so I added

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
```

in dependencies. A lot of errors disappeared but this error occurred instead.

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]

Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\AkerbergE\AndroidStudioProjects\incident\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/NOTICE.txt
    Origin 1: C:\Users\AkerbergE\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.2.3\118ae1bc7f3aeeddfe564f0edfd79c11d09d17d1\httpmime-4.2.3.jar
    Origin 2: C:\Users\AkerbergE\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.2.2\b76bee23cd3f3ee9b98bc7c2c14670e821ddbbfd\httpcore-4.2.2.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt
    File 1: C:\Users\AkerbergE\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.2.3\118ae1bc7f3aeeddfe564f0edfd79c11d09d17d1\httpmime-4.2.3.jar
    File 2: C:\Users\AkerbergE\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.2.2\b76bee23cd3f3ee9b98bc7c2c14670e821ddbbfd\httpcore-4.2.2.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.903 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.TXT'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akerberge.incident"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually in your code you have written

`exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.TXT'`

instead of this write:

`exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'`

so, your `build.gradle` file look like:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akerberge.incident"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

     packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' 
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
    }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
}
```

Comment: I have both         exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        And exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.TXT'

Comment: clean and rebuild project and see what else you getting?

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg and please show me your build.gradle too

Comment: i added tje build.gradle in the description